# How to create different data with each different user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Im using asp.net entity framework and asp.net identity, and what im trying to do is to register with some account and to make some data with user#1(agentmi6) like:

[image]

and then log in with user#2(john) and make some data with this user:

[image]

so my main problem is how to make users view only their created data.

Comment: Do you know anything about relational databases?

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's a **very broad** topic that cannot be handled in a Q & A format. I would suggest you start learning about [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). Your question should be immediately answered as you go through the first steps, but as you will see, it's really a broad subject matter covering various options/frameworks. Hth..

Comment: @EdSF i just added 5 lines of codes in all and i got what i wanted, i dont see that as a very broad topic.

Comment: Good for you congratulations! I'm sure going through EF, db contexts, etc. and its concepts and how it (can) relate to ASP.Net Identity helped narrow it down to however few lines it took. Best ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my movie model i added a relation with application user

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Genre{ get; set; }


        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

then in MoviesController added this query to get all movies created by the current registered user:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var movies = db.Movies.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserID == currentUser);
            return View(movies);
        }
```

and in the Create action of the controller when i create a movie i add the current user to that movie

```
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                movie.ApplicationUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Movies.Add(movie);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(movie);
        }
```

in all Views of MoviesController i removed the application user html since i dont want to show in index and when creating movies.

and in the end i got what i was looking for.

Login with user a@a.com and made a movie which is only visible to him,

[image]

and second user v@v.com that can see only his movie.

[image]